# Why does the GPU usage in Windows 10 Task Manager not sum up to 100%?

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, task-manager

Looking at the task manager, Arma 3 is using nearly 100% of the GPU yet somehow Nvidia gets another 10% squezeed in.

[image: Screenshot of the task manager.]

Comment: And your question is. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVIDIA graphics cards have a feature called GPU Boost, which allows the GPU to utilize more than 100% (approx. 110%). The GPU will dynamically overclock itself for greater performance under heavy load.